# Unexpected token in JSON.parse

Tags: javascript, json

I'm using node and request js to `get` a json object from a 3rd party api. When I try to `parse` the data i get an error:

`SyntaxError: Unexpected token`

I then tried to parse the data in my front-end application which resulted in the following error (see the whitespace after token):

`SyntaxError: Unexpected token  in JSON at position 294512`

So i tried to run it through Postman and see what was wrong. The returned JSON seems valid, and I also ran i through a JSON validator without problems.

After investigating the result a bit more i found that one attribute (Document Type) always had a white space inside double qoutes:

```
{
"F24434": {
    "Posting Date": "29-10-12",
    "Open": "No",
    "On Hold": "",
    "Document Type": " ",
    "External Document No.": "",
    "Due Date": "29-10-12",
    "Description": "xxxx",
    "Order No.": "",
    "Currency Code": "DKK",
    "Remaining Amount": "0",
    "Original Amount": "0",
    "Amount": "0",
    "User ID": "xxx",
    "Systemdato": "29-10-12",
    "Entry No.": "607121",
    "Vessel No.": "",
    "Port No.": ""
  }
}
```

I'm not sure if that causes the problem or could it be something else?

Unfortunately I don't have direct access to the API, so I cannot alter the way the data i structured.

**Solution**
It turned out that it was the whitespace inside the double quotes. The solution was to remove all whitespaces before parsing:

`.replace(/\s/g, '');`

Comment: Is that the whole JSON, or is there stuff after the comma `,` at the end?

Comment: It's followed by more items. I will correct it so it doesn't confuse.

Comment: What does the JSON look like 294512 bytes into the stream?

Comment: Is there any tool to find the character at 294512 bytes?

Comment: Are you sure this really is a whitespace and not some other character?

Comment: looks like a zero width space or some non-ascii character in the error.

Comment: Did you try to use .trim() on the result?
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_trim_string.asp

Comment: I'm not sure it's the whitespace. I can't seem to properly locate the error. I did try to use `trim()` without success.

Comment: What you can try, if you have the json as a string, is `console.log(s[294512])`, to try to log the offending character. If that doesn't print anything, it's probably an encoding problem.

Comment: `console.log(data[294512])` prints a whitespace.

Comment: How do you get it? Can you get it as plain-text, clear "Document Type" via regexp and then parse as json?

Comment: ´data.replace(/\s/g, '');´ did the trick! I didn't realize that a white space inside double quotes would trigger an error. Thanks for the help! I will update my question with a solution.

Comment: It wouldn't and shouldn't trigger an error.. are you absolutely sure it was a whitespace and not a character that looked like one?

Comment: Hmm you might be right. But I can't see any character.

Comment: Please add the answer as an answer and then accept that (with as many details as you can...)

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem and in my case it turned out that the string had many null chars appended at the end. Solved it with `myString.split(String.fromCharCode(0)).join("")`.

A whitespace inside double quotes seems to me like a perfectly valid string. I don't think that was the issue in your case.

Comment: For anyone having problem with parsing json after decrypting with Blowfish, this is your solution.